# renaming file uploaded based on its input type's attribute(id) asp.net in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

**View:**

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Edit","program","",FormMethod.Post,new {enctype = "multipart/form-data"}))
 {

   <div class="upload">

     <input type="file" name="files" id="EpExpert"/>
     <input type="file" name="files" id="EpNewbie"/>
     <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" id="submit"/>
   </div>

 }
```

**Controller:**

```
[HttpPost]

public ActionResult Edit(tr_program program, IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
{
  foreach (var file in files)
  {
            if (file != null)
    {
      //string extension = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
      string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Documents/Program-PDFs/";
      string filename = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
      file.SaveAs(Path.Combine(path, filename));
    }
  }
}
```

uploaded file name should be in file-{id}.pdf

eg: file-EpNewbie.pdf

```
file-EpExpert.pdf
```

PLEASE help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `id` is never sent to the server. You could use the `name` attribute instead:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "program", null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <div class="upload">
        <input type="file" name="EpExpert" />
        <input type="file" name="EpNewbie" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" id="submit"/>
    </div>
}
```

and in your controller action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(tr_program program)
{
    string location = Server.MapPath("~/Documents/Program-PDFs");
    foreach (string name in Request.Files)
    {
        HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[name];
        string filename = string.Format("file-{0}.pdf", name);
        filename = Path.Combine(location, filename);
        file.SaveAs(filename);
    }

    ...
}
```

Obviously since you are storing all the files in the same location (`~/Documents/Program-PDFs`) with the same names (`file-EpExpert.pdf` and `file-EpNewbie.pdf`) if 2 users upload different files at the same time they might get overwritten. There seems to be a problem with your design and naming convention but in my answer I illustrated how you could pass the name of the file input to the controller action which could be used to build the resulting filename. Now it's up to you to take this into consideration when building your real application.

Comment: But since i am uploading multiple files, each should have different names,how it can be done with Request.Files?

Comment: I was able to use the above answer in my application similar to how you wanted to use it Kadeer.  Let me knwo if you need details and I can post an answer for you.

Comment: I have a bunch of files being sent with the same name, in an enumerable - is there any other attribute that gets sent to the server?

Answer (score 0):

You can take an idea from here. Firstly declare `id` and `data-id` dynamic. for example

```
id = '@model.Id'   data-id = '@model.Id'
```

Before submit form, use js or jquery take id value, then post form.

```
$("#myForm").submit(function () {
        var idValue = $(this).attr('data-id');
        document.getElementById('yourHiddenValue').value = idValue;
});
```